# Why does my pose change when I try to change it

Tags: animation

I am trying to change the pose of my charachter in pose mode. I am working on animations for a whole week and it worked every time. But suddenly when I try to change the pose in a certain frame, it sets itself back. For example: My charachter has a T-pose in frame 22, when I change the pose to a sitting pose in frame 22 and click on frame 23 and on 22 again, the pose I gave it is gone and the T-pose is back. Why does it do this all the sudden? I need help. If you need a video I can upload it. Thanks!

Comment: Without a .blend file, my guess would be you have autokey turned off when you had made the sitting pose on 22.  Because nothing got keyed, the previous keys' settings got re-evaluated when you scrubbed to frame 23 and then back to 22.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer, I'll look into it later this evening and I'll let you know if it worked or not!

Comment: I have autokey turned onn and when I change the pose of my character I do see the keyframes in the action editor. Do you have any other ideas? If you wan't I could send you the blend file.

Comment: Sure post the .blend on pasteall.org/blend

Comment: I posted the blend on http://pasteall.org/blend/40908 the password is "Thanks". Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I hope you can find the problem!

Comment: So I took a look at it and I managed to give it a T-Pose, so for now my problem is fixed. But the problem stil persists. You don't have to try to fix it anymore, if you wan't to and can then that would be fantastic but for now I fixed it. Thanks for the help Mike!